# Why does COUNT(*) does the same as COUNT(column) in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am finishing a SQL course and they have a query example that I don't quite understand.

I have
[these tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgRT4.png)
and I need to get how many ['etiquetas'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhE3.png) (tags in Spanish), are in each post, so they have this solution:

```
SELECT posts.titulo, COUNT(*) num_etiquetas
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_etiquetas ON posts.id = posts_etiquetas.post_id
INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = posts_etiquetas.etiqueta_id
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY num_etiquetas DESC;
```

I have been trying to understand this query and two questions came up:

1. Why `COUNT(asterisk)` does the same as `COUNT(etiquetas.nombre)`? For me only the latter makes sense, I don't quite understand why `COUNT(asterisk)` works in the given solution, isn't `COUNT(*)` supposed to count the total number of rows? maybe the issue is that I don't really understand how `GROUP BY` really works.
2. Why does deleting this line doesn't change the result? What is its use in the original solution?

   ```
   INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = posts_etiquetas.etiqueta_id
   ```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` will behave the same as `COUNT(nombre)` assuming that all values in the `nombre` column are not null.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` count rows, while `COUNT(<expression>)` count non-null values. They may coincide sometimes, but they are conceptually counting different sets.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts the rows amount in the rowset regardless of the values. `COUNT(column)` counts the amount of non-NULL values for specified column in the rowset. When column does not contain NULLs then these values are equal otherwise the former value is greater. When two columns have no NULL value then `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(column1)` and `COUNT(column2)` will produce the same value.